# Call function from another class in main via linkedlist class

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

Please, help me...
I have Student class, LinkedList class and struct Node. I want to get Student's(object) name in main and I have so many errors. I'm not understanding typedef for calling the function.

There my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Student{
public:
string name;
int age;
Student(string n, int a){
    name = n;
    age = a;
}
Student(){};

void showname(){
    cout << "My name is: " << name << endl;
}

void showage(){
    cout << "My age is: " << age << endl;
}
};

template<class T>struct Node{
    T value;
    Node<T>* next;
};

template<class T>class LinkedList{
        typedef void (T::*fn)();
    public:
        Node<T>* first;
        Node<T>* temp;
        LinkedList(){
            first = NULL;
        }

    void insert(T a2){
        Node<T>* new_node = new Node<T>;
        new_node->value = a2;
        new_node->next = first;
        first = new_node;
    }

    void call(T b, fn op){
        (b.*op)();
    }

    void show(){
        temp = first;
        while(temp!=NULL){
            cout << temp->value;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Student s1("Nurbolat", 18);
    int a = 1;
    LinkedList<int> l1;
    LinkedList<Student> l2;
    l2.call(s1, &Student::showname);
    l2.call(s1, &Student::showage);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef void (T::*fn)();
```

create an alias `fn` as a member function of type `T`, receives no parameter and return `void`

Since `int` is a primitive type, it doesn't have any member function.

It's not required but it's allowed to instantiate all member function of `LinkedList`, then `LinkedList<int>` may give an error.

Remove that typedef and replace:

```
void call(T b, fn op){
    (b.*op)();
}
```

with:

```
template <typename F>
void call(T b, F op){
    (b.*op)();
}
```

then it should works